# Почему z-index не работает на первом элементе моей диаграммы

Tags: html, css, z-index

Столкнулся с проблемой z-index"а на первом элеменьте
[image: Описание проблемы]

```css
.container {
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
  overflow: hidden;
  border-radius: 50%;
  position: relative;
}

.sector {
  width: 50%;
  height: 50%;
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  top: 0;
  transform-origin: left bottom;
}
div.bouble{
  display: inline-block;
  width: 100%;
}

.containers:after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  width: 50%;
  height: 50%;
  background: #fff;
  border-radius: 50%;
  top: 25%;
  left: 25%;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>JS Bin</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" type="text/css"/>
</head>
<body>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.0.0.js"></script>
<div class="container">
  <div class="sector" style="background: rgb(51, 102, 204); z-index: 0; transform: rotate(0deg) skewY(180deg);">
    <div class="bouble">
      <input type="radio" style="position: relative; background: white; float: left; width: 10px; right: 10px; height: 10px; border-radius: 100%; z-index: 100; margin-top: 5px;">
    </div>
  <div class="bouble">
      <input type="radio" style="position: relative; background: white; float: left; width: 10px; right: 10px; height: 10px; border-radius: 100%; z-index: 100; margin-top: 30px;">
    </div>
    <div class="bouble">
      <input type="radio" style="position: relative; background: white; float: left; width: 10px; right: 10px; height: 10px; border-radius: 100%; z-index: 100; margin-top: 30px;">
    </div>
    <div class="bouble">
      <input type="radio" style="position: relative; background: white; float: left; width: 10px; right: 10px; height: 10px; border-radius: 100%; z-index: 100; margin-top: 25px;">
    </div>
</div>
  <div class="sector" style="background: rgb(220, 57, 19); z-index: 0; transform: rotate(90deg) skewY(149.76deg);">
    <div class="bouble">
      <input type="radio" style="position: relative;background: white;float: left;width: 10px;right: 10px;height: 10px;border-radius: 100%;z-index: 100;margin-top: 5px;transform: skew(0deg, 30deg);">
    </div>
    <div class="bouble">
      <input type="radio" style="position: relative;background: white;float: left;width: 10px;right: 10px;height: 10px;border-radius: 100%;z-index: 100;margin-top: 30px;transform: skew(0deg, 30deg);">
    </div>
    <div class="bouble">
      <input type="radio" style="position: relative;background: white;float: left;width: 10px;right: 10px;height: 10px;border-radius: 100%;z-index: 100;margin-top: 30px;transform: skew(0deg, 30deg);">
    </div>
    <div class="bouble">
      <input type="radio" style="position: relative;background: white;float: left;width: 10px;right: 10px;height: 10px;border-radius: 100%;z-index: 100;margin-top: 25px;transform: skew(0deg, 30deg);">
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="sector" style="background: rgb(255, 153, 0); z-index: 0; transform: rotate(149.76deg) skewY(150.12deg);">
    <div class="bouble">
      <input type="radio" style="position: relative; background: white; float: left; width: 10px; right: 10px; height: 10px; border-radius: 100%; z-index: 100; margin-top: 5px; transform: skew(0deg, 30deg);">
    </div>
    <div class="bouble">
      <input type="radio" style="position: relative; background: white; float: left; width: 10px; right: 10px; height: 10px; border-radius: 100%; z-index: 100; margin-top: 30px; transform: skew(0deg, 30deg);">
    </div>
    <div class="bouble">
      <input type="radio" style="position: relative; background: white; float: left; width: 10px; right: 10px; height: 10px; border-radius: 100%; z-index: 100; margin-top: 30px; transform: skew(0deg, 30deg);">
    </div>
    <div class="bouble">
      <input type="radio" style="position: relative; background: white; float: left; width: 10px; right: 10px; height: 10px; border-radius: 100%; z-index: 100; margin-top: 25px; transform: skew(0deg, 30deg);">
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="sector" style="background: rgb(17, 150, 24); z-index: 0; transform: rotate(209.88deg) skewY(150.12deg);">
    <div class="bouble">
      <input type="radio" style="position: relative; background: white; float: left; width: 10px; right: 10px; height: 10px; border-radius: 100%; z-index: 100; margin-top: 5px; transform: skew(0deg, 30deg);">
    </div>
    <div class="bouble">
      <input type="radio" style="position: relative; background: white; float: left; width: 10px; right: 10px; height: 10px; border-radius: 100%; z-index: 100; margin-top: 30px; transform: skew(0deg, 30deg);">
    </div>
    <div class="bouble">
      <input type="radio" style="position: relative; background: white; float: left; width: 10px; right: 10px; height: 10px; border-radius: 100%; z-index: 100; margin-top: 30px; transform: skew(0deg, 30deg);">
    </div>
    <div class="bouble">
      <input type="radio" style="position: relative; background: white; float: left; width: 10px; right: 10px; height: 10px; border-radius: 100%; z-index: 100; margin-top: 25px; transform: skew(0deg, 30deg);">
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="sector" style="background: rgb(153, 1, 153); z-index: 0; transform: rotate(270deg) skewY(180deg);">
    <div class="bouble">
      <input type="radio" style="position: relative; background: white; float: left; width: 10px; right: 10px; height: 10px; border-radius: 100%; z-index: 100; margin-top: 5px;">
    </div>
    <div class="bouble">
      <input type="radio" style="position: relative; background: white; float: left; width: 10px; right: 10px; height: 10px; border-radius: 100%; z-index: 100; margin-top: 30px;">
    </div>
    <div class="bouble">
      <input type="radio" style="position: relative; background: white; float: left; width: 10px; right: 10px; height: 10px; border-radius: 100%; z-index: 100; margin-top: 30px;">
    </div>
    <div class="bouble">
      <input type="radio" style="position: relative; background: white; float: left; width: 10px; right: 10px; height: 10px; border-radius: 100%; z-index: 100; margin-top: 25px;">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Что вы называете первым элементом и как должно работать?

Comment: первые 5 radio элементов должны быть поверх всего. На каждой грани должно быть 5 radio элементов

Comment: У секторов одинаковый `z-index`, поэтому последний сектор накрывает первый.

Comment: Как можно решить эту проблему?

Comment: Переверстайте так, чтобы инпуты не были внутри сектора